# Filter/subset specific column

Tags: r

Despite this very simple problem I can not find the correct solution.

I have data that look like this approx:

```
 ID    Cov1 Cov2 YN
1004   0.45 0.21 0 
1004   0.32 0.43 1
1007   0.36 0.47 0
1007   0.25 0.67 0
1009   0.56 0.34 0
1009   0.12 0.39 1
1021   0.16 0.31 0
1021   0.24 0.76 1
```

I would like to subset or filter those rows of this dataframe that contain 0 and 1 at the same time for the given ID. As you can see the ID=1007 has YN=0 for both rows, so I would like to have this removed.

I have tried among other things something like this, which doesn't work, where DF is dataframe.

```
subset(DF, DF$YN=="1"&DF$YN=="0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be plenty of solutions with `data.table`. One of them -

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt2 <- dt[,Both01 := length(unique(YN)), by = 'ID'][Both01 > 1][,Both01 := NULL]
```

Output -

```
> dt2
     ID Cov1 Cov2 YN
1: 1004 0.45 0.21  0
2: 1004 0.32 0.43  1
3: 1009 0.56 0.34  0
4: 1009 0.12 0.39  1
5: 1021 0.16 0.31  0
6: 1021 0.24 0.76  1
```

Comment: I actually think people should start using data.tables over data.frames. I don't see any advantages of the data.frames over datatables.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use tools from base R, e.g. a combination of `?ave` and `?anyDuplicated`:

```
# import your example data
df <- read.table(textConnection("
ID    Cov1 Cov2 YN
1004   0.45 0.21 0 
1004   0.32 0.43 1
1007   0.36 0.47 0
1007   0.25 0.67 0
1009   0.56 0.34 0
1009   0.12 0.39 1
1021   0.16 0.31 0
1021   0.24 0.76 1"), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## find IDs with duplicated YN values
dups <- ave(df$YN, df$ID, FUN=anyDuplicated)
dups
# [1] 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0
# (a value != 0 means there is a duplicated value at position, e.g. 2)

subset(df, dups == 0)
#    ID Cov1 Cov2 YN
#1 1004 0.45 0.21  0
#2 1004 0.32 0.43  1
#5 1009 0.56 0.34  0
#6 1009 0.12 0.39  1
#7 1021 0.16 0.31  0
#8 1021 0.24 0.76  1
```